# Expansion of polynomial to power of N creates 1001 terms. Find N

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

For some particular value of $N$, when $(a+b+c+d+1)^N$ is expanded and like terms are combined, the resulting expression contains exactly $1001$ terms that include all four variables $a, b,c,$ and $d$, each to some positive power. What is $N$?

The solution includes a use of stars and bars (which I generally understand), but how they manipulated the problem to make stars and bars applicable here confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every unlike term in the expansion of $(a+b+c+d+1)^N$, ignoring the coefficient, can be formed by placing four bars among $N$ stars and interpreting the number of stars in each bin as the exponent of a variable: $a,b,c,d$ or $1$ (the last one indicating no variable). For example, with $N=12$:
$$a|bb|cccc|d|1111=a^1b^2c^4d^11^4$$
Since the question is about terms with all four variables $abcd$ we may set one of each aside and instead place four bars among $N-4$ stars:
$$abcd\quad |b|ccc||1111$$
1001 such terms exist, so we are looking for $N$ with
$$\binom{N-4+4}4=\binom N4=1001$$
and solving we find that $N=14$.

Comment: when the question says "contains exactly 1001 terms that include all four variables a,b,c, and d, each to some positive power," are they saying that each and every one of those 1001 terms will include a, b, c, and d?

Comment: @user405569 Why, yes! The exponent for each of these variables in each such term will be at least one.